# Can't change labels' font color. Chartkick Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-visualization, chart.js, bar-chart, chartkick

I am trying to display a bar chart with legends and labels in white, so i tried this code below on my view, but it didn't do nothing, and my continues displaying the default color.

```
      <%= bar_chart opfh, height: "150px", width: "450px", library: {chartArea: {top: 50,right: 50,bottom: 15,left: 130}, legend: { position: "left", labels: { fontSize: 16, backgroundColor: "none", fontColor: "#fff"} }, colors: ["#0526FF", "#FFFFFF"]} %>
```

**Is there no way to solve this issue?**

[image: This is how my chart looks]

**This is how my chart looks**

**Edit:** Thanks to @WhiteHat answer i cold resolve this! Actually i was trying to change vAxis colors instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming you're creating a [BarChart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart) from Google Charts,
see the [configuration options](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart#configuration-options)...

for the legend, need to use --> `legend.textStyle` -- (not `legend.labels`)
and the following options do not exist...

```
legend.textStyle.backgroundColor
legend.textStyle.fontColor
```

for font color, use --> `color`

```
legend: { position: "left", textStyle: { fontSize: 16, color: "#fff"} }
```

Comment: tried as your answered, but it still didnt do nothing

Comment: `<%= bar_chart opfh, height: "150px", width: "450px", library: {chartArea: {top: 50,right: 50,bottom: 15,left: 130}, legend: { position: "left", textStyle:{color: "#fff", fontSize: 16}}, backgroundColor: "none", colors: ["#0526FF", "#FFFFFF"]} %>`

tried this, but chartkick doesnt render bar chart properly

Comment: are you referring to the labels next to the bars? that's not the legend. that would be --> `vAxis.textStyle` -- also, will you please share the link to the chart kick documentation?